# Toggling two CSS animations with jQuery only works once through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle between two CSS animations using jQuery, but they only work once! How can I get it to keep toggling? Also, this doesn't seem to work in jsFiddle at all for some reason. Please and thank you.

```js
//hide and show counter-button
$('#counter-button').click(function() {
  $('#counter').toggle();

  //move button down/up on click
  if ($('#counter-button').attr('class') === 'movedown') {
    $('#counter-button').addClass('moveup');

  } else {
    $('#counter-button').addClass('movedown');
  }
});
```

```css
#counter-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 190px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.movedown {
  animation: down ease forwards 0.5s;
}

@keyframes down {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}
.moveup {
  animation: up ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes up {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
}
#counter {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 228px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter-button">
  COUNTER
</div>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.attr('class') === 'movedown'` check class using `hasClass()`. And while adding `moveup` class you should remove the `movedown` class and vice-versa.

Check the code below here.

```js
//hide and show counter-button
$('#counter-button').click(function() {
  $('#counter').toggle();

  //move button down/up on click
  if ($('#counter-button').hasClass('movedown')) {
    $('#counter-button').addClass('moveup').removeClass('movedown');
  } else {
    $('#counter-button').addClass('movedown').removeClass('moveup');
  }
});
```

```css
#counter-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 190px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.movedown {
  animation: down ease forwards 0.5s;
}

@keyframes down {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}
.moveup {
  animation: up ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes up {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
}
#counter {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 228px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter-button">
  COUNTER
</div>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan initially OP doesnt have either of the class in his HTML, so `toggleClass` will either remove both or will add both. It could be done using `toggleClass` if `moveup` is already present there.

Comment: ah yes, you're right. My bad. Although I'd suggest adding a default state class to the element to prevent ambiguity and make the JS simpler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes true! :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove the unnecessary class and hence unexpected behavior. Just add `removeClass` and remove respective classes. Snippet below

```js
//hide and show counter-button
$('#counter-button').click(function() {
  $('#counter').toggle();

  //move button down/up on click
  if ($('#counter-button').attr('class') === 'movedown') {
    $('#counter-button').addClass('moveup').removeClass('movedown');

  } else {
    $('#counter-button').addClass('movedown').removeClass('moveup');
  }

});
```

```css
#counter-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 190px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movedown {
  animation: down ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes down {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}
.moveup {
  animation: up ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes up {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
}
#counter {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 228px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter-button">
  COUNTER
</div>

<div id="counter">

</div>
```

**Updated Code**

Further you can optimize the above code by initially adding class `moveup` to your `button` and then you can just use `toggleClass` without checking for any condition.

```js
//hide and show counter-button
$('#counter-button').click(function() {
  $('#counter').toggle();
  //move button down/up on click
    $(this).toggleClass('movedown moveup');
});
```

```css
#counter-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 190px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movedown {
  animation: down ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes down {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}
.moveup {
  animation: up ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes up {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
}
#counter {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 228px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter-button" class="moveup">
  COUNTER
</div>

<div id="counter">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleClass

```js
     //hide and show counter-button
    $('#counter-button').click(function() {
      $('#counter').toggle();

        $('#counter-button').toggleClass('moveup movedown');


    });
```

```css
#counter-button {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 90px;
  bottom: 190px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.movedown {
  animation: down ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes down {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
}
.moveup {
  animation: up ease forwards 0.5s;
}
@keyframes up {
  from {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  to {
    right: 90px;
    bottom: 190px;
  }
}
#counter {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  width: 228px;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter-button" class="moveup">
  COUNTER
</div>

<div id="counter">

</div>
```